# Fine-tuned GPT-3.5 Turbo for Classification: Unexpected Responses Outside Defined Classes

Tags: python, openai-api, large-language-model

I am currently fine-tuning the "gpt-3.5-turbo-1106" model for event severity classification in four classes - 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd'. The training data consists of event details, including name, description, location, associated risk, and severity label.

Here's how I prepared the training data:

```
    system_message = "This model is trained to classify the potential severity of events into four categories: { a , b , c , d }. These classes represent increasing levels of severity, with 'a' being the least severe and 'd' being the most severe. Please provide a response that accurately reflects the severity of the event."

    completions = []
    for _, row in df_hazards.iterrows():
        event_name = row['summary']
        event_description = row['detailed_description']
        impact_type = row['potential_severity_type']
        potential_severity = row['categorical_severity']
        exact_place = row['exact_location']
        risk = row['risk_event_title']
        prompt = textwrap.dedent(f"""\
        Event Name: {event_name}
        Event Description: {event_description}
        Exact Place: {exact_place}
        Impact Type: {impact_type}
        Associated Risk: {risk}""")
        # Remove all indentations at the beginning of each line
        prompt = re.sub(r'^\s+', '', prompt, flags=re.MULTILINE)
        completions.append({'messages': [{'role': 'system', 'content': system_message}, {'role': 'user', 'content': prompt}, {'role': 'assistant', 'content': potential_severity}]})
```

After creating the model using OpenAI's API, when I validate it with different event scenarios, I notice that the model provides responses outside of the defined classes 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd'. I specified in the system message that the model should focus on these classes.

Top logprobs from the model's responses include unexpected tokens like 'Event', 'Action', 'Safety', etc., which are not part of the defined classes.

I should note that my classes are imbalanced, with counts as follows: 'a': 663, 'b': 146, 'c': 58, 'd': 10.

Is there a way to fine-tune the existing model to better align with my defined classes? If not, what recommendations do you have for creating a new model that accurately classifies events into the specified severity classes?

Any assistance or insights would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with fine-tuning GPT 3.5 but I'm doing classification with prompt tuning and few-shot prompts.

This might also help here after fine-tuning. You could try something like this:

````
To which category does this event belongs?
- [a]
- [b]
- [c]
- [d]

Events are enclosed in tripple ```

Example event 1:
```
{some sample event goes here}
```
Category:
[a]

# and so on ...

Event to classify:
```
{event}
```
````

Depending on the prompt format you can then write the first word of the answer:

```
### Assistant:
Category:
```

This helps to get the model to always start with the category. The [] brackets help to identify the category in the models answer.

Further tips:

- Use a good name for your category like [Low], [High] instead of a, b. This might help the model as well.
- Let the model writhe an explanation after the category. With a further instruction like "Give your explanation after the category.".

Hope this helps :)